# Can I communicate with an Atmega32U4 through USB during runtime?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, atmega32u4

I'm designing a PCB circuit to do PID control using sensor data to control a robot. I'm new to using micro-controllers other than Arduino and I'm having some trouble figuring out exactly how everything fits together.
What I want to be able to do is figure out the inverse kinematics in Matlab and send the desired angles to the micro-controller from my computer.  I've started to put together a schematic for an Atmega32U4 (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7766-8-bit-AVR-ATmega16U4-32U4_Datasheet.pdf) based circuit because it has built in USB support and for now I am okay with powering my board through USB as well.
But I don't understand exactly what I will be able to do with a basic USB connection to the micro-controller.  Will I be able to send data while the circuit is running to command angles for the robot?  Is that just a question of the micro-controller's code?  My circuit is basically the same as this one in terms of USB connection: https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/please-help-review-my-atmega32u4-board

I'm not particularly attached to this exact micro-controller if there is an easier option.  I just don't know what that would be.  The only real constraint on the micro-controller I use is that it has to have at least 3 ADC input pins and at least 3 PWM output pins

Comment: Yes, but not *easily*.  Something with a UART and a distinct USB-UART conversion will be easier to develop for...

Comment: There are Arduino boards based on this exact MCU, and there are USB CDC libs for these. Could be even *simpler* than using USB2UART chip...

Comment: investigate Arduino Leonardo